# How to configure Teamcity to build a project which is a plugin of a different project?

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity

I have a project which is a plugin for an opensource system. In order to run a CI build for the plugin, it needs to be installed into an existing instance of the main opensource system. I have mostly got this working, however, the install procedure for the main system is long and complex, so the build takes forever. It is also awkward to set up as checking out the plugin from git always happens first, whereas it needs to happen after the main system has been put in place so that the right directories are there. The solution I have right now is to use a shell script for the install and then an Ant task for the build, ignoring built-in VCS altogether. Feels hacky, though.

Two solutions come to mind:

1. Have a persistent install of the main system in the build directory, which the plugin is added to at the start of the build, and removed from at the end. I didi this ith Jenkins and it worked OK, but we are now using TeamCity.
2. Have some sort of parent-chid relationship between two CI projects, so that the main one is built and then triggers the plugin one, which is built within it. This would allow the main one to be rebuilt whenever it needs to be and avoids the awkwardness of keeping an install of the main system clean between builds.

However, I don't know enough about TeamCity to know if this is possible. Has anyone ever done something like this before?

Answer (score 2):

For your solution number 2 you can try to use the "Build Triggers" configuration, the "Finish Build Trigger" option should resolve your parent-child relationship very well.

In TC, go to your plugin's build configuration, in "Configuration Steps" section select "Build Triggers" (number 5), then select "Add New Build Trigger" and configure "Finish Build Trigger" selecting your main system's build configuration.

To use parent directory in child one, you'll need to use the "Artifact Dependency" (see "Dependencies" section in "Configuration Steps", maybe setting some snapshots between the build configurations too.

> [Artifact Dependencies](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Dependent+Build#DependentBuild-ArtifactDependency): 
>   artifact Dependencies provide you with a convenient means to use the
>   output (artifacts) of one build in another build. When an artifact
>   dependency is configured, the necessary artifacts are downloaded to
>   the agent before the build starts.
>
> [Snapshot Dependencies](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Snapshot+Dependencies): by setting a dependency of a build (e.g. build B) on other build's (build A's) sources, you can ensure that build B will start only after the one it depends on (build A) is run and finished
>
> [Configuring Finish Build Trigger](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Configuring%20Finish%20Build%20Trigger): 
>   finish build trigger triggers a build of current build configuration if a build of selected build configuration is finished

Comment: Sounds good. Is it possible to specify the child's build directory to be within the parent's one, so that the parent's files are part of the build?

Comment: Answer updated, added some information about artifact dependencies.